# How to work with managed transactions in MongoDB in NestJS?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, nest

I'm currently working on a NestJS application with MongoDB as the database backend. I need to implement managed transactions for handling multiple database operations within a single transaction.

Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to work with managed transactions in MongoDB within a NestJS application?

Example using [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#managed-transactions)

```
try {

  const result = await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {

    const user = await User.create({
      firstName: 'Abraham',
      lastName: 'Lincoln'
    }, { transaction: t });

    await user.setShooter({
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Boothe'
    }, { transaction: t });

    return user;

  });

  // If the execution reaches this line, the transaction has been committed successfully
  // `result` is whatever was returned from the transaction callback (the `user`, in this case)

} catch (error) {

  // If the execution reaches this line, an error occurred.
  // The transaction has already been rolled back automatically by Sequelize!

}
```

Comment: You can check out this doc(https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html). You create a session and pass it as a parameter in the CRUD functions. Kind of similar to the code you have posted.